# Convert data frame to frequency table in R

Tags: r, frequency-analysis

Using R, I converted a frequency table (created using the `table()` function) to a data-frame. My data frame now looks as follows:

```
            words       frequency
1           'home'      1
2           'paper'     5
3           'letter'    6
```

Now I want to convert this data frame back into a `table()` object.

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
my.data <- data.frame(words=c("home", "paper", "letter"),
                      frequency=c(1, 5, 6))
my.tbl <- xtabs(frequency ~ words, data=my.data)
is.table(my.tbl) # TRUE
```